# Where is Webb Space Telescope?

Tags: rockets, nasa

In this NASA application page [Where is WEBB?](https://webb.nasa.gov/content/webbLaunch/whereIsWebb.html) about the recently launched Webb space telescope the information provided tracking the cruising speed of the telescope widely changes (i.e. dropped from 0.9 mi/s to 0.55 mi/s) from hour to hour or on different days.

I thought that during its cruise the Webb telescope would maintain a constant speed.

Are these large speed variations due to course corrections or due gravitational effects or whatever other reason(s)?

Comment: Related : https://space.stackexchange.com/q/57480/46

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The speed is dropping, and it will continue to drop to almost zero.

The reason being that the telescope is currently moving away from the Earth, so Earth's gravity is pulling it back, slowing it down.

Spacecraft cruising are not under engine power, so they are entirely at the mercy of gravitational forces. Instead, spacecraft do their orbital changes in small impulses, "burns", and the rest of the time, the freefall cruising, their velocity naturally increases and decreases depending on whether they are going up or down. Jumping out of a plane, you're in freefall downwards, so your velocity increases. James Webb is in freefall upwards, so its velocity is decreasing.

There are some course corrections too, but the changes you are seeing are mostly due to good old gravity.

Comment: "The speed is dropping, and it will continue to drop to almost zero." That's not true. I'm observing the speed several days now and there are also  relatively large speed ups. But in general the speed will drop to zero at the end I guess.